# backend_cleanup takes no arguments

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

We are using:
celery==3.1.20
django-celery==3.1.17

Whenever the backend_cleanup is invoked (once a day?)
we get the following exception:

```
Got exception in task [60b4b41b-b9a6-461a-bfbd-9d40869c06dc]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lacoon_web/mt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lacoon_web/mt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: backend_cleanup() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

This error started when we upgraded django-celery from 3.1.10 to 3.1.17 and django from 1.6.11 to 1.8.14

Appriciate your help
Dekel

Comment: How you are running celery, command ?

Comment: ./manage.py celery beat -S tenant.tenant_celery.TenantPersistentScheduler --broker=<RABBITMQ URL>

./manage.py celery worker -c 2 --broker=<RABBITMQ URL>

Comment: django-celery is not updating now a days.So use `celery -A project beat` to start beat scheduler. and like worker also

Comment: backend_cleanup()  -what exactly does it clean? what happens if I don't clean every day but once a week?

Comment: If you dont want to cleanup , `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES =None` in settings.py. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: what happens if I don't clean? memory issues?

Comment: Not any issues, results will save in db.Thats the only thing

Comment: will the results be overridden when a task runs next time? what is the key for a database result  entry?